# What is <compatible-screens> and <uses-gl-texture> in Android Market filtering?

Tags: android, google-play

I received an email from Google Android Market Support stating :-

> Market will support filtering based on screen sizes and densities, as well as on GL texture compression formats. Filtering is based on `<compatible-screens>` and `<uses-gl-texture>` elements in an app’s manifest.

However I don't see `<compatible-screens>` or `<uses-gl-texture>` in the documentation.  Are these new features, or is it a typo for `<supports-screens>` and `<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="..." />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very old question, but since now they have been documented:

[`<compatible-screens>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html)

> **Description**
>
> Specifies each screen configuration with which the application is compatible. Only one instance of the `<compatible-screens>` element is allowed in the manifest, but it can contain multiple `<screen>` elements. Each `<screen>` element specifies a specific screen size-density combination with which the application is compatible.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> <compatible-screens>
>     <screen android:screenSize=["small" | "normal" | "large" | "xlarge"]
>             android:screenDensity=["ldpi" | "mdpi" | "hdpi" | "xhdpi"] />
>     ...
> </compatible-screens>
> ```

The `<uses-gl-texture>` seems to be renamed to `<supports-gl-texture>` in production.

[`<supports-gl-texture>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-gl-texture-element.html)

> **Description**
>
> Declares a single GL texture compression format that is supported by the application.
>
> An application "supports" a GL texture compression format if it is capable of providing texture assets that are compressed in that format, once the application is installed on a device. The application can provide the compressed assets locally, from inside the .apk, or it can download them from a server at runtime.
>
> Each `<supports-gl-texture>` element declares exactly one supported texture compression format, specified as the value of a `android:name` attribute. If your application supports multiple texture compression formats, you can declare multiple `<supports-gl-texture>` elements. For example:
>
> ```
> <supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture" />
> <supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture" />
> ```

Both elements, just as mentioned in the question, is for filtering only (on Android Market/Google Play Store, or by other apps). **Android doesn't check the app compatibility on install-time & runtime**.